# libgdx - wait to complete an action of an actor

Tags: libgdx, action, delay, wait, actor

My problem is I want an actor to do an action (in this case a fade) and just after the end of the action, switch to the game screen. But the action is finished not complete, but quickly changed the game screen.

I want to wait to complete this action before changing the screen .. And in general, I wonder how I can make waiting instructions in the game, because it is sometimes good to want to allow some time before anything happens.

```
myActor.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(2));
setScreen(AnotherScreen);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is create an `Action` subclass and override `Action#act` where you will call `setScreen(AnotherScreen);`.

Then, use `Actions#sequence` to wrap both actions into a single `SequenceAction` object.

```
Action switchScreenAction = new Action(){
  @Override
  public boolean act(float delta){
    setScreen(AnotherScreen);
    return true;
  }
};

myActor.addAction(Actions.sequence(
  Actions.fadeIn(2)
  , switchScreenAction
));
```

For more info, check out: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#complex-actions

Answer (score 4):

Use the static imports for actions, way easier.

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.*;

Actor.addAction(sequence(fadeOut(2f), run(new Runnable() {
     public void run () {
         System.out.println("Action complete!");
     }
});
```

Put the code you want to run in the runnable.

For more info,

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions